# Unhandled event loop exception and Editor could not be initialized in LibreOffice Extension Java Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, libreoffice, add-on, libreoffice-basic

I just started developing desktop application which can communicate to libreoffice of linux using libreoffice extensions.

I am trying to run [Github LibreOffice Extension Code Sample](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension).
Its showing error "Editor could not be initialized" and log below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openoffice.ide.eclipse.core.editors.RegDocumentProvider.createDocument(RegDocumentProvider.java:98)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.FileDocumentProvider.createElementInfo(FileDocumentProvider.java:721)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDocumentProvider.connect(AbstractDocumentProvider.java:392)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4178)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1466)
at org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor.doSetInput(TextEditor.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2184)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2180)
```

Its also showing some U letter on the project folder  and D letter on types.rdb file below in blue colour. What does that mean?

[image]

While running this project its showing error "Unhandled event loop exception" and error log below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.libreoffice.ide.eclipse.core.launch.office.OfficeLaunchShortcut.createDefaultLaunchConfiguration(Unknown Source)
at org.libreoffice.ide.eclipse.core.launch.office.OfficeLaunchShortcut.launch(Unknown Source)
at org.libreoffice.ide.eclipse.core.launch.office.OfficeLaunchShortcut.launch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runInternal(LaunchShortcutAction.java:85)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5227)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1134)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5227)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4561)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4151)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I tried creating some sample project using File->New->Project->OpenOffice->Extension Project. Still getting those same error below.
[image]

Also I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074189/unhandled-event-loop-exception-in-plugin-org-eclipse-ui) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581740/eclipse-cdt-could-not-open-editor-editor-could-not-be-initialized) but still no positive result.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was due to project was runnning as LibreOffice Extension.

To solve the issue I created a new configuration with name LibreOffice Application (Instead of extension). Its running smoothly now.